# $(window).scrollTop using angular.element($window); in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to emulate this in AngularJS with JavaScript:

```
$(window).scrollTop(
    $scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] ? 
    $scope.scrollPos[$location.path()] : 0);
```

I know that I can replace $(window) with var windowElement = angular.element($window);

But is there a way that I can emulate the scrollTop functionality?

For reference here's the code I using:

```
    $rootScope.scrollPos = {}; // scroll position of each view

    $rootScope.scrollClear = function (path) {
        $rootScope.scrollPos[path] = 0;
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.okSaveScroll = false;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
        function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            var windowElement = angular.element($window);
            $timeout(function () { // wait for DOM, then restore scroll position
                windowElement.scrollTop($rootScope.scrollPos[$location.path()] ? $rootScope.scrollPos[$location.path()] : 0);
                $rootScope.okSaveScroll = true;
            }, 0);
        })
```

Comment: Have you tried `$anchorScroll`?

Comment: Have you tried $window.pageYOffset?

Comment: @GevorgHarutyunyan - I didn't try that yet. Do you think I can just plug that in and it will replace scrollTop ?

Comment: Yes, I think angular is watching for $window.pageYOffset change.

Comment: But isn't the functionality here to make the change not watch for the change?

Comment: `$anchorScroll.scrollTo` is what you're looking for. Caching view positions is not a good choice because they are changeable.